# How to bul ant(run) project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a problem with Eclipse ant configuration. I tried to export my java project an ant in Eclipse and everything seems ok. But when I try to run ant from the Windows console with Ant, my program is compiling correctly, but it does not start/run.

What should I do if I want to run my Eclipse project from console?

Comment: could you please show your code as what you are trying ?

Comment: Code is ok, but i think i have incorrect build.xml.It contain target compile, the target run is missing :)

Comment: When you run your code within Eclipse, that usually includes a 'launch configuration' that will launch/run your code.   Did the export of the project include anything like that?   If you are missing the 'run' target, then it sounds that may not be part of the export project process.